# 16.04 on ESXi 6 Screen Resolution

Tags: screen, display-resolution

I created an Ubuntu Server 16.04 VM on VMWare ESXI 6.  I have installed Ubuntu Desktop on the server as well.  We I try and change the screen resolution my vm will freeze.  What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 5):

Turn off your Virtual Machine on which Ubuntu is installed and change the "Total Video Memory" to 8MB under Video card settings by clicking link Edit virtual machine settings.

Answer (score 2):

I just found!!

It's the graphic memory! default configuration is not enaugth!

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2168763&p=12762734#post12762734

I set 10Mo in VideoMemory (in ESXI6 VM configuration) and all good now

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about how you solved the issue? Link-only answers are not very useful to others.